# SQLite System.NotSupportedException: Don't know how to read <T>

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I develop application with Xamarin Forms and Sqlite.
I use folowing nugets:

1. sqlite-net-pcl
2. SQLiteNetExtensions

I want create query with sql.

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `AuditFormDto` (
    `AuditDtoGuid`  varchar,
    `Id`    integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `Guid`  varchar,
    `AuditFormTradePointDtoId`  integer,
    `CreationLocationJson`  varchar,
    `CompletionLocationJson`    varchar,
    `CreationDate`  bigint,
    `CompletionDate`    bigint,
    `Status`    integer,
    `PlaceInAudit`  integer,
    `CreatorId` varchar,
    `ServerId`  integer,
    `AuditServerId` integer,
    `ShouldSync`    integer,
    `Deleted`   integer
);
```

And

```
CREATE TABLE `AuditDto` (
    `CreatorId` varchar,
    `RegularQuestionIdsBlobbed` varchar,
    `CreationLocationJson`  varchar,
    `CompletionLocationJson`    varchar,
    `Guid`  varchar NOT NULL,
    `DateCreated`   bigint,
    `DateFinished`  bigint,
    `Name`  varchar,
    `Comment`   varchar,
    `Type`  integer,
    `Status`    integer,
    `ServerId`  integer,
    `ShouldSync`    integer,
    PRIMARY KEY(`Guid`)
);
```

Also I created wrapper class

```
public class JoinedClass 
{
    public string AuditDtoGuid { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string Guid { get; set; }
}
```

But when I try execute this code:

```
public async Task<JoinedClass> Get(int id)
{
    var strQuery = $"SELECT * FROM AuditFormDto INNER JOIN AuditDto ON  AuditDto.Guid = AuditFormDto.AuditDtoGuid where AuditFormDto.Id = {id}";
    var joinedClass = await _connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<JoinedClass>(strQuery);
    return joinedClass;
}
```

I have this Exception :

```
System.NotSupportedException: Don't know how to read JoinedClass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExecuteScalarAsync` return the effected count not rows result.

you can change using `QueryAsync`.

it looks like:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<JoinedClass>> Get(int id)
{
    var strQuery = $"SELECT * FROM AuditFormDto INNER JOIN AuditDto ON  AuditDto.Guid = AuditFormDto.AuditDtoGuid where AuditFormDto.Id = {id}";
    var joinedClass = await _connection.QueryAsync<JoinedClass>(strQuery);
    return joinedClass;
}
```

[image]

Comment: what's the exception message. look picture it work fine.